# Are there other clans than the Hyuga with the Byakugan

Tags: naruto

naruto shippuden episode 389 (dubbed) at 2:45 a maid reveals that

> "The Hyuga is a distinguished clan *-pause* within the leaf we are the only ones who posses the Byakugan"

Does this mean that there are clans who posses the Byakugan other than the Hyuga outside of the leaf village?

Comment: The Otsutsuki Clan are the original owners of the Byakugan, the Hyuuga Clan is descended from them

Comment: So the Hyūga knew of the Otsutsuki when Hinata was ~10?

Answer (score 5):

The Byakugan actually originated from the Ōtsutsuki Clan. As revealed in **Chapter 671** and as stated in the wiki, the [Byakugan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Byakugan)

> originated from the Ōtsutsuki Clan and was later inherited by their distant descendants, the Hyūga Clan.

Outside the leaf village, I can only recall [Ao](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ao) as the known possessor of the Byakugan but it should be noted that this was stolen and not inherited, like that of the Hyūga Clan.

Comment: @TheIrishPizzaGuy I don't see understand the point you're trying to make when you mentioned that scene. Referring to someone as Byakugan user does not mean they don't recognize him/her as a Hyūga. In fact, they would probably conclude he's from the Hyūga clan since they are the well-known users of Byakugan.